# Is there a way to get current order (place) of an element in a collection?

Tags: php, laravel

I mean this:

```
$collection = collect([['a' => 2], ['b' => 5], ['b' => 10]]);
$order = $collection->getOrderOf(['b' => 5]);
// $order should be 1 (if the first element is 0, second - 1, third - 2 and so on)
```

Is there something similar to this or I should make a collection extension?

Thanks

Comment: you made an error with `b=>10` it should be `c=>10`

Comment: No, it is not a typo. It is just an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in your case:

```
$collection = collect([['a' => 2], ['b' => 5], ['b' => 10]]);
$pair_to_search = ['b' => 10];
$order =  $collection->values()->search(function ($item) use ($pair_to_search){
        $key = key($pair_to_search);
        foreach($item as $k => $v){
            if($k==$key && $v==$pair_to_search[$key])
                return $item;
        }
});
if($order)
{
       //you have index, do what you want
}
```

Comment: This looks promising.. But I had to remove "->values()" and also change "foreach($item .. " to "foreach($item->toArray() .. " Thanks

Comment: its just some procedures, new ideas are always welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

The method you're looking for is `search`. This method accepts a value and returns a key that corresponds to it if it is in the collection. It returns `false` if the value could not be found.

```
$collection = collect([['a' => 2], ['b' => 5], ['c' => 10]]);
$collection->search(['a' => 2]); // 0
$collection->search(['b' => 5]); // 1
$collection->search(['c' => 10]); // 2
$collection->search(['c' => 11]); // false
```

I've just run the above code using Laravel Tinker (Version 5.5) and it seems to work without any issues.

Comment: Check the `array`.

Comment: What about the array? I know the OP has two `b` keys, but assumed it was a typo. The resulting collection would only have two values if it was intended. I changed it to `c` in my answer to illustrate.

Comment: I don't think this does the job.. the collection is not consisted of numerical values but pretty complex associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
$collection = collect([['a' => 2], ['b' => 5], ['b' => 10]]);
$check = ['b' => 5];
$index = $collection->search(function ($value, $key) use($check) {
    // return key if key value pair matches
    return serialize($value) === serialize($check) ? $key : false; 
});
echo 'Found at - ' . $index;
```

**Output**

```
Found at - 1
```

Comment: I think this would not work is the matching is not full.
What if I got collect([['a' => 2], ['b' => 5, 'c' => 7], ['b' => 10]]); but want to search by ['b' => 5].

Comment: In that case it would not work. Then have to match with key value pair separately.